# Cycling animation of rainbow-coloured text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

**CYCLING COLORS ON HOVER With JavaScript/jQuery**

I'm trying to take a block of text, color each letter according to calculated position between HSL 0deg and 360deg, and on hover animate the colors to the right. I know this is weird, but bear with me. ***What I want is animated rainbow text on hover.***

I've covered the logic of making all of this happen once, but can't get hover cycling behavior to work.

**here is a link to the codepen.io:** http://cdpn.io/txmlf

I've tried using JavaScript mouse events and jQuery's .hover(). My initial thought was to set an interval on mouse enter and clear it on exit.

I'd truly appreciate any help on this obviously very important project.

Comment: Obviously very important project  +1

Comment: Yeah, you didn't see the kickstarter campaign? :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might wanna think about how this'll affect UX, but what about this: http://jsfiddle.net/7Xuep/6/

Ok, so rotating through all the colours of the rainbow is easy enough using CSS-animations. The issue is then linking them up to all your span tags such that the animation starts in the right place. (i.e. you need the green letter to start it's animation from the colour green etc.) To do this, we can use `animation-delay`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

which we can use to start the rainbow animation at the appropriate colour for each letter. By using a `linear` timing function, it's simple to determine at what time the animation will arrive at each colour. Therefore, it's just a matter of attaching the right `animation-delay` value to each `<span>` element. I do that by just taking your already generated HTML and adding in the CSS rules to each element's `style` attribute:

```
var animTime = 6, // time for the animation in seconds
    hueChange = 3, // the hue change from one span element to the next
    prefixes = ["", "-webkit-", "-moz-", "-o-"],
    numPrefixes = prefixes.length;

$('.unicorn').find('span').each(function (i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < numPrefixes; j++) {
        $(this).css(prefixes[j] + 'animation-delay', (animTime * ((i * hueChange) % 360) / 360) - animTime + 's');
    }
});
```

but you could do this at the same time as you're generating all your `span` elements.
Then it's just a case of setting up the animation using CSS:

```
.unicorn:hover span {

    animation: colorRotate 6s linear 0s infinite;

}

@keyframes colorRotate {
    from {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
    16.6% {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    }
    33.3% {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }
    50% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    }
    66.6% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    83.3% {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

All this gets us to here: http://jsfiddle.net/P6WVg/7/

Now, if you don't want the colours to reset once someone is no longer hovering over `.unicorn` then you can use `animation-play-state`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state

However, I was finding that Chrome has an issue with combining an initial value of `-webkit-animation-play-state:paused;` and a negative value of `-webkit-animation-delay` such that it just displayed the first frame (i.e. `color: rgb(255,0,0);` in this case). Therefore I had to use an event listener to add a class containing the animation CSS on the first hover, and this leads us to:

http://jsfiddle.net/7Xuep/6/

(that bug in chrome can be tracked here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=269340)

Comment: Yo, I was trying to avoid adding any CSS to the style sheets, yet manipulate the CSS with js. Wanted to take advantage of hardware acceleration, yet leave all needed code in a single js file. Your answer was immensely helpful, so I'll select this as correct, but it'd be great if you had any advice on doing what I described above.

Comment: @Todd this should insert the CSS dynamically using JS: http://jsfiddle.net/BYoassrian/7Xuep/4/

Comment: @Todd Opera seemed to be having issues with dynamically injecting the CSS like that so I made a slight tweak to get it working: http://jsfiddle.net/BYoassrian/7Xuep/5/

Comment: Sry it's taken so long for response. Incredible work, my friend. You got the bounty correct? Thank you so much.

Comment: I know this is 4 years old, but on a hardware accelerated performance note,, is this still probably the best method? I know gradients are slow as hell on mobile.. what do you guys think?

Answer (score 2):

Why not keep it simple, (with only your HTML) **this is all you need:**

[**Live demo**](http://jsbin.com/eZUwUZE/3/edit)

```
var step = 4, // colorChage step, use negative value to change direction
    ms   = 10,  // loop every
    $uni = $('.unicorn'),
    txt  = $uni.text(),
    len  = txt.length,
    lev  = 360/len,
    newCont = "",
    itv;
alert(lev+' '+len);

for(var i=0; i<len; i++)newCont += "<span style='color:hsla("+ i*lev +", 100%, 50%, 1)'>"+ txt.charAt(i) +"</span>";

$uni.html(newCont); // Replace with new content
var $ch = $uni.find('span'); // character

function stop(){ clearInterval(itv); }
function anim(){
  itv = setInterval(function(){
    $ch.each(function(){
      var h = +$(this).attr('style').split(',')[0].split('(')[1]-step % 360;
      $(this).attr({style:"color:hsla("+ h +", 100%, 50%, 1)"});
    });
  }, ms); 
}

$uni.hover(anim,stop);
```

<sub>Tested in FF, Chrome, Opera</sub>

Comment: I really like this solution, as well. My only question regards the var "lev." lev seems to be zero for lengths greater than 360. @Roko

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity, @Roko. I didn't understand why you were using the parseInt() method with a radix of 10. This returns 0 when the txt.length is greater than 360. To remedy this, i set lev to 360/len. when I iterated through chars, I set hue = (Math.ceil(i*lev)<=360)? Math.ceil(i*lev) : 360

Comment: @Todd edited, you were completely right, I don't know why I used parseInt... Thanks for the note

Comment: How do I make it work without hover, so it will repeat for the element always

Comment: @IdanShechter see at the bottom of JS: http://jsbin.com/eZUwUZE/4/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan how can I limit the color range from blue to green only?

Comment: @IdanShechter I'm not going to do it for you. It's quite simple, the `h` variable represents the hue. Hue values are from 0 to 360. Homework: find in what range are green and blue. Limit the `h` variable to that range (instead to the whole 360).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks, I'll do it now.

Comment: I know this is 4 years old, but on a hardware accelerated performance note,, is this still probably the best method? I know gradients are slow as hell on mobile.. what do you guys think?